# Code coverage percentage in unit testing

Tags: python, asp.net, .net, unit-testing

I have a class, having 3 methods(in python) .

```
class MyClass:
    def A(self):
          .......
    def B(self):
         ........
    def C(self):
         ........
```

I have written unit test case for only one method A. This unit test covers each line of the method A. That is we don't have any if...else or any branching constructs.

What would  be the code coverage percentage?

Again if I write another unit test case for 2nd method of the class covering all lines.  What would be the code coverage percentage now?

Comment: It really depends on your three methods. Even without branching and other control flow constructs, dependency between the methods in question can affect the coverage.

Comment: Assume all three methods are independent of each other. No inter calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer myself :-)

Code coverage is all depends on which module or which files you are running the coverage for. Lets say if we run coverage for one file the way i had framed my question. Each line in each method will be accounted for code coverage.

Now as per my question i am covering only one method contain 20 lines. Other 2 methods have another 80 lines (total 100 lines in 3 methods). So if i ran coverage for my file. I would get code coverage of only 20%.

In python we can run (in pycharm terminal) like :coverage run -m py.test my_file.py
To get the report run the command :coverage report -m py.test my_file.py

To run for entire module (in all packages) use : coverage run -m py.test and coverage report -m py.test